# subdivide the products in "percent categories"?

Tags: price, custom-prices

we want to have 3 buttons on our webpage where we want to subdivide the most of our articles in 3 groups:

first group: 50-60%

second group: 60-70%

third group:  over 70%  of  the normal UVP - shop price...

because we are an outlet shop!

Is there any module update for magento 1.9 ?

Answer (score 0):

Create an attribute, add the percentage range to it and use the layered navigation for this.